# How to get the last 3 months in date partitions

Tags: hiveql

I have a hive table partitions on date column . Now I want to get the last 3 months of it as it runs every day.

```
show partitions test;
OK
test_month=2019-05-01
test_month=2019-06-01
test_month=2019-07-01
test_month=2019-08-01
test_month=2019-09-01
```

`datediff(test_month, to_date(CURRENT_DATE)) >= 90;`

`test_month <= DATEADD(MONTH, 90, GETDATE());`

Expected result:
Get all the date that is in last 3 months partition;

Desired Output:
`select DISTINCT(test_month) from test where test_month <code>`

should give :

```
test_month=2019-07-01
test_month=2019-08-01
test_month=2019-09-01
```

Comment: are you looking for last three months partition data or just a last three months partitions columns as you shown above.. it can be done using Hive and shell both depending on what you are trying. Can you please clear? I have a little confusion here.

Comment: I am looking for last 3 months data using hive.

Comment: @ settle.. well you have answer below with an explanation also. Can you edit your question and change below line as: Expected result: Get all the data that is in last 3 months partition;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your hive version but since [`1.1.0`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9357) supports `add_months` :

```
select current_timestamp();

+--------------------------+--+
|           _c0            |
+--------------------------+--+
| 2019-09-03 17:10:30.396  |
+--------------------------+--+
```

Since you want `data >= '2019-07-01'` you need to do `-2` with trunc.

Taking `current_timestamp()` as reference, If its automated process and you want same date then you can use as it is or it can be any `date` Datatype value.
It will be like below:

```
select DISTINCT(test_month) from test 
where test_month >= add_months(trunc(current_timestamp(), 'MONTH'), -2)

select add_months(trunc(current_timestamp(), 'MONTH'), -2) ;
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2019-07-01  |
+-------------+--+
```

**Just For Information:**

**trunc(TIMESTAMP date, STRING unit)**

> Strips off fields and optionally rounds a TIMESTAMP value. The unit
>   argument value is case-sensitive. This argument string can be one of:
>   SYYYY, YYYY, YEAR, SYEAR, YYY, YY, Y: Year. Q: Quarter. MONTH, MON,
>   MM, RM: Month. WW, W: Same day of the week as the first day of the
>   month. DDD, DD, J: Day. DAY, DY, D: Starting day of the week. (Not
>   necessarily the current day.) HH, HH12, HH24: Hour. A TIMESTAMP value
>   truncated to the hour is always represented in 24-hour notation, even
>   for the HH12 argument string. MI: Minute.

**add_months(TIMESTAMP date, BIGINT|INT months)**

> Returns the specified date and time plus some number of months.

Exact -3 months , not start of the month

```
select add_months(current_timestamp(), -3) ;
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2019-06-03  |
+-------------+--+
```

Start day of -3 months date:

```
select add_months(trunc(current_timestamp(), 'MONTH'), -3) ;

+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2019-06-01  |
+-------------+--+
```